# Getting grub terminal after removing Ubuntu partition and unable to boot into Windows

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, dual-boot, boot-loader, rescue

I deleted my Ubuntu partition cause I wanted to install Linux mint. But now when I switch on my laptop, I'm unable to boot into Windows. I'm getting a grub terminal (not sure if it's grub rescue mode) on startup. It says: Gnu grub version 2.02^beta2-9ubuntu1.3 Minimal bash like line editing is supported For the first word, tab lists possible command completions. Anywhere else tab lists possible device or file completions . grub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've encountered that same issue before. You have to run `update-grub` once you delete a partition, but I didn't so grub didn't know about the changes to the disk. I follow the tutorial [How to Rescue a Non-booting GRUB 2 on Linux](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776643-how-to-rescue-a-non-booting-grub-2-on-linux/), but in your case if you want to boot into Windows, what specific settings are necessary there.

I'd suggest the easier way - go to friends with a PC, create Linux Mint installation USB, and install Mint. The installer should detect Windows partition, and let you choose to install along-side Windows.

Comment: I made a mint live usb and connected it to my laptop but when I switch on my laptop the same screen comes up?

Comment: You need to boot from that USB, not from your hard drive. Press F12 or F8 on bios screen. Which button to press will be specific to your model. Also you could temporarily change boot order in bios, but you'd need to change that after you're done installing mint